# Selecting n balls from N - Cumulative Distribution Function

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

I am having difficulty with the following question:

Suppose that N balls labelled $\{1, 2, . . . , N\}$ are placed in a box, and n balls ($n ≤ N$ ) are randomly selected without replacement. Define the random variable $X$ = largest number selected. Find the probability function for $X$

I was able to find the answer to this question by letting $f(x)$ be the probability function so that $$f(x) = P(X=x) = \frac{\binom{1}{1}\binom{x-1}{n-1}}{\binom{N}{n}}$$

I'm having trouble finding the same function $f(x)$ using the cumulative distribution function defined by $F(x)$. I know that $F(x) = P(X\le x)$ but I don't know how to use this information to find $F(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need just the principles that you've already applied to find $f$. You selected $1$ from $1$ and $n-1$ from $x-1$ to make sure that $X=x$ holds exactly. If you don't want $X=x$ but only $X\le x$, you just need to stop forcing one to be exactly $x$, so you get

$$
\frac{\binom xn}{\binom Nn}\;.
$$

You can derive $f$ from $F$ and vice versa by applying [Pascal's rule:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_rule)

$$
\binom xn-\binom{x-1}n=\binom{x-1}{n-1}\;.
$$

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how $\binom{x}{n}$ will satisfy that $X\le x$? that is where I seem to be confused.

Comment: @Daniel: $X\le x$ means that all individual values are $\le x$. There are $\binom xn$ ways to choose $n$ values among the $x$ values that are $\le x$.